# how to express solution only in terms of some variables in sympy.solve?

Tags: python, programming

How to express this solution in terms of r, g, and phi?

```
import sympy as sp
m, N, phi, v, g, r = sp.symbols('m N phi v g r')
sp.solve((-N*sp.sin(phi)+m*v**2/r,N*sp.cos(phi)-m*g),v, dict=True)
```

yields:
$\left[ \left\{ v : - \sqrt{\frac{N r \sin{\left(\phi \right)}}{m}}\right\}, \  \left\{ v : \sqrt{\frac{N r \sin{\left(\phi \right)}}{m}}\right\}\right]$

The result I want is $v:\sqrt{rgtan(\phi)}$

as derived in: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/pages/week-3-circular-motion/11-2-worked-example-car-on-a-banked-turn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the variable you want to eliminate to the list of variables you want to solve for.

```
>>> sp.solve((-N*sp.sin(phi)+m*v**2/r, N*sp.cos(phi)-m*g), v, N, dict=True)

[{N: g*m/cos(phi), v: -sqrt(g*r*tan(phi))}, {N: g*m/cos(phi), v: sqrt(g*r*tan(phi))}]
```